# Disable multiple numbers after zero in input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" step="0.1"/>
```

However, I can still type something like:

> 0000 or 000111 or 00223, etc.

in my input field. How can I limit it only to one 0?

Is there a way to do this in HTML only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your input starts with zero and override next digits with only 0.

```js
function checkZero(){
  var val = document.getElementById("num").value;
  if(val.startsWith("0")){
     document.getElementById("num").value = "0";
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" min="0" oninput="checkZero()" step="0.1"/>
```

Comment: I just LOVE the use of .startWith() here, completely forgot about it!! Thanks. :))

Comment: What about '0.2'? I guess this should be accepted as well

Comment: @borkovski, give me a min please :)

Comment: @eric.dummy yes, javascript has many utility functions like startsWith(), so often we forget about using them. If this approach works, could you please accept the answer as well. Cheers

Comment: There you go. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this:

```
while (s.charAt(0) == '0') {
    if (s.length == 1) { break };
    if (s.charAt(1) == '.') { break };
    s = s.substr(1, s.length-1)
}
```

It accepts numbers like 0.1 and handles 00.1 or 001.